# Table Refresh, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have had some previous help with this script from a lovely member of the community (Oshawott) but I am stuck on what seems to be a small error that I don't know how to fix relating to Jquery. Just to double check I think I have implemented Jquery in my script properly but as I am still new I am struggling to find what is wrong. It says it is a "Unterminated string constant" and it comes from the `$(document).ready(function refresh(){` section. Unfortunately I have found no way to solve this and I have read various forums but I cant seem to fathom it. I hope you guys can help me and I appreciate any time you give to help me get better.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function refresh() { 
    // This function takes every table cell with dusky class 
    // and inserts output of duSky() into it
    $($dusky).each(function () {
        this.html = duSky();
    });
});
```

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<body bgcolor="33FF00">
<script language = "JavaScript">


function duSky(){                                                   //This is a function to tell add points to the points variable if the user clicks a duck.
    duckNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
    if(duckNum<10){document.write("<img src=images/skyTile.jpg>")}
    else{document.write("<img src='images/duckTile.jpg' onClick='duckClick()'")}
    }


</script>


<td class='dusky'></td>




<center><img src=images/duckHuntTitle.gif><br>                  <!Duck Hunt title gif, no background so you can see the background of the page, also centered>



                                    <!Named the table "TableDiv" so that I can refer to it at a later date. This was to try and make my job of refreshing easier>   
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>

        </tr>                                                       <!Inside of all the table boxes there is a function that designates whether inside will be a duck or sky tile>
        <tr>                                                        <!This is the duck table that is exactly 1000px wide by 400px height. This is created by 10 200px by 200px boxes, two rows of 5 boxes>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        </tr>
        </table>


<form name="score">
Points <input type="text" name="pointsscored" readonly="readonly">  <!This is the box that is centered that displays the points the player has got, also is now readonly so no tweaking is allowed>
</form>

<form name="timer">
Time <input type="text" name="timeBox" readonly="readonly">         <!This is the timer box that is centered as well that displays how long the player has left and is readonly>
</form>
</center>


<script language = "JavaScript">                                    //Returns the script to JavaScript to allow for functions to be used that are related to the HTML previous to this




$(document).ready(function refresh(){                               // This function takes every table cell with dusky class and inserts output of duSky() into it
    $($dusky).each(function(){
        this.html = duSky();
    })
})

setInterval(refresh, 1000);                                         // Make our refresh script run every 5 seconds

timeLeft = 30                                                       //this is counted down from until it hits 0
points = 0                                                          //this is the points system that is added to by 10 each time a duck is clicked

document.timer.timeBox.value = timeLeft                             //Displays the time left before the game has even started and been clicked so the player immediately knows the time that they have to play with


function timeDecrease(){                                            //This is the timer function that reduces the timer by a second each time to make the game slowly time out after 30 seconds
setInterval(function(){timeLeft--                                   //I am still working on the refresh function but hopefully it will be corrected to make the table refresh with every 1000 miliseconds
document.timer.timeBox.value=timeLeft;
//document.tableDiv.reload(true)                                    //trying to get the reload function to work.
},1000);                                                            //1000 miliseconds, therefore it is 1 second
}


while(timeLeft < 0){alert("Timeeeeeees Up, you scored: ", points ,"points! well done Duck Slayer!")}    //Alert to signify the end of the game.


// ----------------Function for clicking the duck-----------------


function duckClick(){
points = points + 10;
document.score.pointsscored.value = points;                         //when the player clicks the duck, points will be added to the points box
}




</script>
<center>


<form name = "playButton"> 
<button type="button" onClick = "timeDecrease()">Play!</button>     <!This is the on click function that starts the game/countdown feature>


</center>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

take out the `refresh`, because you're using an anonymous method (it doesn't have a name)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // rest of code here
});
```

alternatively you could do something like this

```
var refresh = function(){
    // code hrere
}
$(document).ready(refresh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

With in ready function you can write javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

The below code is not right:

```
$(document).ready(function refresh(){                                                           
    $($dusky).each(function(){
        this.html = duSky();
    })
})
```

Replace it with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function refresh () {                                                           
    $($dusky).each(function(){
        this.html = duSky();
    });
  }
  // And if you wanna call the function on load, use this:
  refresh();
})
```

And you are missing a lot of semicolons and some places, the string is not fully closed. For example:

```
duckNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
if(duckNum<10){document.write("<img src=images/skyTile.jpg>")}
else{document.write("<img src='images/duckTile.jpg' onClick='duckClick()'")}
```

Change it to:

```
duckNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); // Semi colon missing
if(duckNum<10){document.write("<img src=images/skyTile.jpg>");}
else{document.write("<img src='images/duckTile.jpg' onClick='duckClick()'>");} // Tag end missing
```

Comment: wouldn't you still have to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // This function takes every table cell with dusky class 
    // and inserts output of duSky() into it
    $('table tr td.dusky').each(function () {
        $(this).html(duSky());
    });
});
```

Comment: Correction: `$('.dusky')` takes every element with the `dusky` class, not just table cells. That would be `$('table tr td.dusky')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try define `refresh` outside ready scope:

```
var refresh;

$(document).ready(function () { 
    refresh = function(){
        $($dusky).each(function () {
            this.html = duSky();
        });
    }
});
```